# linkwrap in gridwidget yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

How can I wrap the link-titel in Html::a($modeld->taguung_bez), when it becomes too long for a responsive presentation. I would like to have same bahavior  like table-data.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'] , 
            [ 'attribute' => 'tagung_kurz_bez',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function($model){
                    **return Html::a($model->tagung_bez, 
                    Url::to(['tagungen/view', 'id' => $model->id]));**

                }
            ],
           ],
    ]); ?>
```